# String must be alphanumeric validation

Tags: ruby, regex

A string must contain both letters and numbers

i tried below regular expression, but it is allow me to add special characters, i don't want any special character in string

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])/
```

Below is my cases

**invalid**

- test
- TEST
- 0123
- T12^

**Valid**

- T123
- 123T
- t123
- 123t

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I see from your tags that you're using Rails. What's wrong with the built-in numericality validator?

Comment: I want alphanumeric value not only numeric value, string must contain both letter and numbers

Comment: Your condition is not clear. "Whether a string contains alphanumeric or not" is not the same as "whether the string contains anything other than alphanumeric".

Comment: /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]*$/ try this. You can play with regular expressions here http://rubular.com/

Comment: @sawa String must contain alphanumeric , not only letters, not only numbers, and not special characters

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy it is not duplicate, check it, i need to check string must contain alphanumeric, your regex will allow if string contains only letters. in my case, string must contain both letter and numbers

Comment: @sawa i updated my question, please check it

Comment: `chrs = str.chars; chrs.all?(/[a-z\d]/i) && chrs.any?(/\d/) && chrs.any?(/[a-z]/i)`

Comment: Is btw `"Ó1"` valid? FYI: `"Ó"` is a letter.

Comment: @mudasobwa "`Ó1`" no its not valid, and it is giving me error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use 2 positive [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` to assert that there is at least a character and at least a digit:

[`^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`](http://rubular.com/r/TRNhIrJZg4)

Or with the case insensitive flag and `\d` to match digits:

[`^(?=[a-z\d]*[a-z])(?=[a-z\d]*\d)[a-z\d]*$`](http://rubular.com/r/zPz5Ocu72v)

Comment: FYI: the above fails on `"A1\n#@&(`^="`. Always use `\A` and `\z` matchers instead of `^` and `$` unless you do pretty fine understand what you are doing.

Comment: @mudasobwa when i used this regex `\A(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]\Z` it is not allowing me this `TTTada41adada` simple alphanumeric. Can you please help me out in this  ?

Comment: The good start would be stop blindly copying the code and go read about [regular expression anchors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors). The trailing `*` is significant otherwise it matches single-character string only.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to check if a string contains letters and digits only and at least one letter and one digit.

You can use the following regular expression which I've written in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \A                   # match beginning of string
    \p{Alnum}*           # match zero or more letters or numbers
    (?:                  # begin non-capture group
      \p{Alpha}\p{Digit} # match a letter followed by a digit
      |                  # or
      \p{Digit}\p{Alpha} # match a digit followed by a letter
    )                    # end non-capture group
    \p{Alnum}*           # match zero or more letters or numbers
    \z                   # match end of string
    /x                   # free spacing regex definition mode

%w| test TEST 0123 T12^ T123 123T t123 123t |.each { |s| puts "#{s}: #{s.match?(r)}" }
test: false
TEST: false
0123: false
T12^: false
T123: true
123T: true
t123: true
123t: true
```